# Hadoop error "exec: /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/bin/hadoop: not found"

Tags: java, hadoop

I am using micheal noll tutorial in setting up single node Hadoop cluster [noll](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/).

But when I run the command

```
hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal /home/proton/Desktop/tmp/gutenberg /user/hduser/gutenberg
```

I get the error:

> **/usr/bin/hadoop: 4: exec: /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/bin/hadoop: not found**

Can anyone please suggest any solution to this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means soft-link `/usr/bin/hadoop` is not pointing to right location check if `hadoop` command exist at `/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/bin/hadoop`, and make `/usr/bin/hadoop` to point to right location that is the location of your `hadoop` installation directory